# How do I trigger the release of a Rust Mutex after a panic in Wasm so that future calls will be ok?

Tags: rust, webassembly

I encountered a deadlock while developing with Rust and WebAssembly.

Due to the use of some globally accessed variables, I choose `lazy_static` and a Mutex (using `thread_local` callbacks would have caused nesting problems). I have declared a lot of Rust functions are used by JavaScript through `#[wasm_bindgen]`. They read and write the `lazy_static` variables.

After one of the functions panics, the mutex lock cannot be released, causing other functions to panic if they need to use the same mutex.

I know that the panic problem is unexpected and needs to be fixed, but these functions are relatively independent of each other. Although the reading and writing of the `lazy_static` variables intersect, a certain bug may not necessarily affect other parts.

How do I trigger the release of the `Mutex` after a panic in Wasm to allow other calls to be ok? Is there any better practice for this kind of problem?

Rust:

```rust
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::sync::PoisonError;
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

pub struct CurrentStatus {
    pub index: i32,
}

impl CurrentStatus {
    fn new() -> Self {
        CurrentStatus { index: 1 }
    }
    fn get_index(&mut self) -> i32 {
        self.index += 1;
        self.index.clone()
    }

    fn add_index(&mut self) {
        self.index += 2;
    }
}

lazy_static! {
    pub static ref FOO: Mutex<CurrentStatus> = Mutex::new(CurrentStatus::new());
}

unsafe impl Send for CurrentStatus {}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn add_index() {
    FOO.lock()
        .unwrap_or_else(PoisonError::into_inner)
        .add_index();
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn get_index() -> i32 {
    let mut foo = FOO.lock().unwrap_or_else(PoisonError::into_inner);
    if foo.get_index() == 6 {
        panic!();
    }
    return foo.get_index();
}
```

JavaScript:

```js
const js = import("../pkg/hello_wasm.js");
js.then(js => {
  window.js = js;
  console.log(js.get_index());
  js.add_index();
  console.log(js.get_index());
  js.add_index();
  console.log(js.get_index());
  js.add_index();
  console.log(js.get_index());
  js.add_index();
  console.log(js.get_index());
  js.add_index();
});
```

After the panic, I can not call the function at all and it is as if the Wasm is dead.

Comment: "*After one of the functions panic, the holding of the mutex cannot be released*" -- why do you think that? What have you tried to check this? Because, as far as I know, mutexes get "poisoned" when a thread holding a lock panics. In that case, you can still use the mutex later. Have you read [this paragraph](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#poisoning)? Does this help or is your question about something different?

Comment: You're not really supposed to recover from panic. A panic isn't just a gentle exception like a JS error, it's the program not able to run anymore.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I don't know if that statement is correct on its own. Yes, people should absolutely not use panics for expected errors and shouldn't use panics as "poor man's exceptions". But there are many situations where it makes sense to "recover" from panics, to start a process again, log errors, and more.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt I added an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before answering this question I should probably mention, that panic handling shouldn't be used as general error mechanism. They should be used for unrecoverable errors.

Citing [documentation.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.panic.html)

> This allows a program to terminate immediately and provide feedback to the caller of the program. panic! should be used when a program reaches an unrecoverable state.

Panics in Rust are actually much more gentle than it may seem in the first place for people coming from C++ background (which I assume is the case for some people writing in the comments). Uncaught Rust panics by default terminate thread, while C++ exception terminate whole process.

Citing [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/index.html)

> Fatal logic errors in Rust cause thread panic, during which a thread will unwind the stack, running destructors and freeing owned resources. While not meant as a 'try/catch' mechanism, panics in Rust can nonetheless be caught (unless compiling with panic=abort) with catch_unwind and recovered from, or alternatively be resumed with resume_unwind. If the panic is not caught the thread will exit, but the panic may optionally be detected from a different thread with join. If the main thread panics without the panic being caught, the application will exit with a non-zero exit code.

It is fine to [catch_unwind](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html) and recover thread from panic, but you should know that `catch_unwind` isn't guaranteed to catch all panics.

> Note that this function may not catch all panics in Rust. A panic in Rust is not always implemented via unwinding, but can be implemented by aborting the process as well. This function only catches unwinding panics, not those that abort the process.

So, we understood that recovering from panic is fine. The question is what to do when lock is poisoned.

Citing [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html)

> The mutexes in this module implement a strategy called "poisoning" where a mutex is considered poisoned whenever a thread panics while holding the mutex. Once a mutex is poisoned, all other threads are unable to access the data by default as it is likely tainted (some invariant is not being upheld).

There is a valid reason for poisoning, because invariants of your data may not be held. Consider `panic!` in the middle of some function. This is just an additional level of security, that you can bypass.

> A poisoned mutex, however, does not prevent all access to the underlying data. The PoisonError type has an into_inner method which will return the guard that would have otherwise been returned on a successful lock. This allows access to the data, despite the lock being poisoned.

```
use std::sync::{Mutex, PoisonError};
fn main() {
    let mutex = Mutex::new(1);

    // We are prepared to face bugs if invariants are wrong
    println!("{}", mutex.lock().unwrap_or_else(PoisonError::into_inner));
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=35cf77eca11cee193da391a78cd7822a)

Of course it's always better to fix panic, than do this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where I was running several integration tests in parallel, and they had a mutex (that was accessed globally), but if one test failed, all subsequent tests would fail as well. This was a problem when I wanted to debug where a test failed, simply because the output would have a lot of other failed tests (due to poison error).

The solution was to simply use the [parking_lot](https://crates.io/crates/parking_lot) crate (a library for using mutexes), which seems to clear the mutex if the thread crashes.

Sadly I didn't find anything in the documentation that explains how it works, or if it even guarantees this behavior in future versions. But the current version works well for me, and if it works for you, it's easier than the accepted answer, since all you have to do is replace `sync::Mutex` for `parking_lot::Mutex` and you are ready to go (and also remove the `.unwrap` to the `lock()`, since it doesn't return a `Result`)